# Image background bottom overflow

Tags: dart, flutter

I can't figure it out how to make this background properly sized to the rest of the screen. Anyone could point me whats wrong ??

I kinda trying to make this fit the rest screen but can;t manage to do it...

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new GradientAppBar('Milkyway Galaxy'),
        new Container(
          child: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildBackground(),
              _buildDescription(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBackground() {
    return new Container(
//      constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
      child: new Image.asset('assets/images/milkyway.gif', fit: BoxFit.cover,),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDescription() {
    return new Container(
      child: new Center(
        child: new Text(milkyWayGalaxy.description),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BoxDecoration` to apply your image as a background image of your `Container`. Use the `Expanded` widget to make sure that the `Container` fills the remaining space of the screen:

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new GradientAppBar('Milkyway Galaxy'),
        new Expanded(
          child: new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage('assets/images/milkyway.gif'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: new Center(
              child: new Text(milkyWayGalaxy.description),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

If the text is longer, you may want to wrap it in a `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: great, this is what I was looking for! Thank you :)